# Error 400 "Invalid JSON payload" when inserting G Suite licenseAssignment with Google Enterprise License Manager API

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-license-manager, google-workspace

I've been using the [Google Enterprise License Manager API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/reference) in Google Apps Script to assign G Suite licenses to users successfully for years. Since last Friday, 4/24/20 I've been getting an `Invalid JSON payload` error back from the API.

I create this object to insert a license assignment:

```
{
  "userId": "user@domain.com",
  "productId": "Google-Apps",
  "skuId": "Google-Apps-Unlimited"
}
```

I use `UrlFetchApp` to call the API from Google Apps Script:

```
{
  "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/Google-Apps/sku/Google-Apps-Unlimited/user",
  "validateHttpsCertificates": true,
  "followRedirects": true,
  "payload": "{\"userId\":\"user@domain.com\",\"productId\":\"Google-Apps\",\"skuId\":\"Google-Apps-Unlimited\"}",
  "useIntranet": false,
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer ya29.xxxx",
    "X-Forwarded-For": "x.x.x.x"
  },
  "method": "post",
  "contentType": "application/json"
}
```

Normally this works but now I've been getting back this response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"productId\" at 'body': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"skuId\" at 'body': Cannot find field.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"productId\" at 'body': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"skuId\" at 'body': Cannot find field.",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I have confirmed that:

- Our domain has G Suite Business licenses, my account is a Super Admin account, and I have enabled the Enterprise License Manager API in the GCP console.
- I am using the correct API endpoint URL and path parameters defined here: [LicenseAssignments: insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/reference/licenseAssignments/insert#request)
- `userId`, `productId` and `skuId` are included in the JSON payload
- I am using the correct `productId` and `skuId` for our domain as defined here: [Google Product and SKU IDs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/how-tos/products)
- The user exists in our G Suite domain
- This affects multiple users that I have tested with, both users with and without current license assignments

As per Google's Developer guidelines I've both asked this question here and submitted an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155165153) in the Google Apps Script IssueTracker.

Comment: Btw, Excellent question with all details, links and research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/reference/licenseAssignments/insert#request), the payload should only contain `userId`. `productId` and `skuId` are just path parameters and including it in the url should be enough.

Request Body:

```
{
  "userId": string
}
```

Comment: Indeed, removing `productId` and `skuId` from the payload worked. I'm guessing it had always been designed to only require `userId` in the body but it had previously allowed the other two properties to exist but discarded them, but now they "fixed" that.